# Why does django queryset only allow me to search users by foreignkey only ( Number) and not by user name?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Am working on this app where users of the app can make payment to other users, but am currently challenge by the search functionality, since i can only search users on the app by their foreignKey only, but instead i would want to be able to search by users full name, email and username, when i search user by name i get this exception (Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Hong'. ). why does my query only limit me to search by user number(foreignKey).Here is my view to search user for payment.

```
class RequestSearchUser(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = FriendList
    form_class = SearchUserForm
    template_name = 'wallet/request_search_user_form.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            username = self.kwargs['search_user']
        except:
            username = ''
        if username != '':
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(username=username)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RequestSearchUser, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get("search_user")
        context['user'] = self.request.user

        if query:
            queryset = (Q(user=query))
            search_user = FriendList.objects.filter(queryset)
            if not search_user:
                messages.error(self.request, 'No user found.')
        else:
            search_user = []

        context['search_user'] = search_user
        context['nbar'] = 'request'

        return context
```

Here is my search form.py

```
class SearchUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].strip()
        return username
```

Here is the Html form

```
  <div class="blog_details">
                            <h2>Request Money</h2><hr>

                            <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="{% url 'wallet:request' %}" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        {% if messages %}
                                            {% for message in messages %}
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                    {{ message }}
                                                </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        {% for search_user in search_user %}
                                            {% if search_user == request.user %}
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                                    Cannot input your username.
                                                </div>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={% url 'wallet:request_money' search_user.id %}" />
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="search_user" id="search_user" type="text" maxlength="45"
                                               onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Username'" placeholder="Username" required/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                    <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Search </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is here

```
object_list = self.model.objects.filter(user=username)
```

and here

```
queryset = (Q(user=query))
```

If you store username of user in field called username, you should filter by user__username

```
object_list = self.model.objects.filter(user__username=username)
queryset = (Q(user__username=query))
```

It's nicely described here [Many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20in%20the%20last%20example%20the%20article%20has%20moved%20from%20John%20to%20Paul.)

Comment: I am still getting the same error Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Hong'.

Comment: You need to change query Q(user=query) to Q(user__username=query) aswell

Comment: It's not throwing the exception again, but still can't search with user full name and email ? how do i do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#containment-and-key-lookups) so your query will look like this

```
if query:
   queryset = (
        Q(user__username__contains=query)|
        Q(user__first_name__contains=query)|
        Q(user__email__contains=query)
   )
   search_user = FriendList.objects.filter(queryset)
   if not search_user:
      messages.error(self.request, 'No user found.')
```

Comment: It didn't work it only allowed me to search the username, it doesn't show any result when first_name and email is search .

Comment: Are you using your SearchUserForm for searching? if yes then you've to add email, first_name in your form fields.